# SQL Pivoting from rows to columns leaves nothing but NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table variable, called `@t`, it is an instance of the specsAndModel type I defined here:

```
CREATE TYPE specsAndModel AS TABLE
(
    specName VARCHAR(50)
    ,specVal VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Doing a `select specName,specVal from @t` gives data of the form:

```
specName              | specVal
--------------------------------
[modelNumber]         | F00-B4R
[Internal Switch(es)] | 2.00000
[Number of Ports]     | 1.00000
[Color Insulator]     | Yellow
```

I inserted the first row so that when I transpose the table, there will be a `modelNumber` field. I intend to join the transposed table to another on that field.

In order to account for a different number of records for different models, I constructed the pivot statement using string concatenation:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',' + specName, specName) FROM @t;

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols 
+ N' FROM @var src' 
+ N' PIVOT (MAX(specVal) FOR specName in (' + @cols + N')) pvt;';
```

The query string looks like this:

```
SELECT [modelNumber],[Internal Switch(es)],[Number of Ports],[Color Insulator] 
FROM @var src 
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(specVal) 
  FOR specName in ([modelNumber],[Internal Switch(es)],[Number of Ports],[Color Insulator])
) pvt;
```

Finally, I use `sp_executesql` to pass in the `@t` variable, then execute the `@query` string:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@var specsAndModel readonly', @t
```

The result is this:

```
[modelNumber] | [Internal Switch(es)] | [Number of Ports] | [Color Insulator]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL          | NULL                  | NULL              | NULL
```

I get the null values for all models, I constructed a toy example of this pivot [here on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/3486/0) and it works as expected. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

How can I transpose this table without getting null values?

Comment: I like this: `SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',' + specName, specName) FROM @t;`! Neat way of doing it. But the problem is that you need to use `QUOTENAME(specName)` as @bluefeet pointed out below (+1 for that bluefeet). [modelNumber] <> "[modelNumber]".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things to fix:

First, remove the `[` from around your `specName` values on your `INSERT` statement.

Second, change the way you get your columns to this. This will add the `[` around the `specName` values:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(specName) 
                    from @t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

If you do that, then your script will work:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(specName) 
                    from @t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols 
+ N' FROM @var src' 
+ N' PIVOT (MAX(specVal) FOR specName in (' + @cols + N')) pvt;';

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@var specsAndModel readonly', @t
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59c9f/3)

Comment: This is second time today you have solved my problem, thank you!